# Add a '~' symbol in the HL7 message

Tags: xslt, vbscript, hl7, hl7-v2

I have an HL7 Message exporting.
There's one field which has a tild symbol (~) in the input.
The HL7 is converting that into symbol "\R\"

I also tried exporting this value by using the ASCII value (126) for the '~' character using VBScript as I am .
But that was also converted by HL7 to "\R\"

How Can I get the '~' exported ? 
Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

HL7 escapes the repetition character "~" to  "\R\" when transferring a message.   The receiver should that change back to your tilde, when working with that field.
But there is a second way to deal with that issue. HL7 allows to change the encoding chars. Unfortunately not all HL7 engines support that.

Comment: Yes, I think those changes are to be made in the HL7 Rollup or somewhere in the config.

Answer (score 5):

This character (~) represents that this field can have multiple values.
Consider this PID.3 field from a given HL7 message

`12345^^^XYZ~6789^^^PQR`

What it means that, the patient has 2 patient ids coming from different sources viz. XYZ and PQR. This is what the (~) character means functionally.

If **I go by the statement in the question body**, I believe you want to achieve the **functionality of (~)**.

To do this, try following below process. I don't know vbscript so I can't give you the code, however I have some Javascript code for the same, and I think you can mimic the same on vbscript. I'll leave that task to you.

```
 //Calculates number of current repetitions by counting the length
 var pidfieldlen=msg.PID['PID.3'].length();

 //Store the last field node
var lastpidnode=msg['PID']['PID.3'][pidfieldlen-1];    //If length is 5,node index is 4 

 //Create new pid field and append with last pid node 
var newpidfield=<PID.3/>                      //Creating new separate element for PID.3
newpidfield['PID.3.1']="567832"               //Adding Field Values
newpidfield['PID.3.4']="NEW SOURCE"
lastpidnode.appendChild(newpidfield)          //Adding above created to the last node
```

This will transform the PID.3 into

`12345^^^XYZ~6789^^^PQR~567832^^^NEW SOURCE`

Comment: In this case the encoding of the repetition character would be wrong. It would loose its meaning escaping the tilde, as it really means a repetition. You only encode it, if it does not mean repetition. e.g. in a value field in OBX

Comment: I am not following you, to answer you more accurately!

Comment: Ok, again.
The question was how to get back the tilde in the content of a field, that was changed by HL7 to "\R\".


You showed how to get the tilde in a repeated field. This answer does not help in any way.

Comment: Well, I did mention I was going by the title of the question. :) It might not help the OP completely, regardless it can be of help to anyone in future. Let's leave it to the OP, shall we?

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the tilde characters with  `&#x7e;` or `&#126;` (decimal). 
See the [unicode reference](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/007e/index.htm) for this character.

If you have already done so, this is not the source of error. I suspect that `HL7` attaches a special meaning to this character. According to [this webpage](http://www.corepointhealth.com/resource-center/hl7-resources/hl7-encoding-characters) it denotes a "Field Repeat Separator".